# Unable to find the jar file having class:weblogic.wsee.security.unt.ClientUNTCredentialProvider

Tags: jar, weblogic

I searched in jar finder and googled.. still I couldn't find the jar that would resolve my import.
Please let me know if any one knows it.

Comment: Which weblogic version you are using?

Comment: I am not aware of the server. I just want my code to get compiled fine. But am not able to find the reference jar that has this class. ClientUNTCredentialProvider

Answer (score 1):

you can find this class in following jar files (11g) :

```
MW_HOME\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar
MW_HOME\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\wls-api.jar
MW_HOME\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\wseeclient.jar
```